# How to run .NET unit tests in a docker container

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a .NET Core application containing MSTest unit tests. What would the command be to execute all tests using this Dockerfile?

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-runtime
ARG source
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "Unittests.csproj"]
```

Folder structure is:

```
/Dockerfile
/Unittests.csproj
/tests/*.cs
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a base image with .NET Core SDK installed. For example:

```
microsoft/dotnet
microsoft/dotnet:1.1.2-sdk
```

You can't run `dotnet test` in a Runtime-based image without SDK. This is why an SDK-based image is required. Here is a fully-workable `Dockerfile` example:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore

# run tests on docker build
RUN dotnet test

# run tests on docker run
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test"]
```

`RUN` commands are executed during a docker image build process.

`ENTRYPOINT` command is executed when a docker container starts.

Comment: Anyone know how to fail the build using the exit code from "Run dotnet test"

Comment: Can someone clarify what the "test" parameter is? is it the unit test method or the unit test project name, also a distinction between the Run and Entry point is needed.

Comment: @eschneider : the "test" parameter is a command line agrument for the "dotnet" command. Both `RUN` and `ENTRYPOINT` commands do the same thing at this Dockerfile. The difference is only *when* the tests are runned. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: So what indications are there that my unit tests are running in docker and for what image? Also does this work when I run from the test explorer?

Comment: @JasonRowe to make the build fail set Environment.Exit(yourCode) when your tests finish. Check for that exit code in your CI scripts.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is also struggling with this question but `dotnet restore` is taking a very long time, I created a Dockerfile below that solved this issue for me:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
WORKDIR /App

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY ./test ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# run tests on docker run
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test"]
```

**Note:** I didn't include `RUN dotnet test` in my Dockerfile as this would stop the build if the tests failed and this did not suit my scenario

I also had a .dockerignore file with the following contents:

```
bin/
obj/
```

For reference, this was my folder structure:

```
/bin/
/obj/
/test/*.cs
/.dockerignore
/Dockerfile
/testing.csproj
```