# How to configure CI for dockerized F# Expecto tests on TFS

Tags: docker, tfs, continuous-integration, automated-tests, expecto

I have some **dockerized** F# tests written by expecto and fscheck frameworks, as a dotnet core **standalone executable**.

How to configure continuous integration on Team Foundation Server to run them and get the report after each run accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you already have the docker image which has the proper SDK/envirement, then you just need to run the image in TFS with CI build ([Configure continuous integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/example-continuous-testing#configure-continuous-integration)).

To run the image, you need to install the [Docker Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker) extension, please refer to [Build, push and run Docker images with Visual Studio Team Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jcorioland/2016/08/19/build-push-and-run-docker-images-with-visual-studio-team-services/) for details.

Other articles may help:

- [Running Selenium Tests in Docker using VSTS Release Management](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/running-selenium-tests-in-docker-using-vsts-release-management)
- [How to run .NET unit tests in a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252037/how-to-run-net-unit-tests-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: @Mohsen Have you resolved the issue? is that help for you? any update?

Comment: :Sorry Andy the last link you provided was useful,but I encountered other issues (such as this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297951/how-to-use-docker-with-paket/48328457#48328457)  in details that interfered testing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Configure Expecto to output NUnit-equivalent XML files with https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expecto.TestResults/

The docs are here https://github.com/haf/expecto/#testresults-file

Then just run the executable and have the CI server pick up the outputted XML file.