# How to use Docker with Paket?

Tags: docker, f#, docker-compose, paket

There are several projects in my solution (some production and some test ...)
and there is a docker image per each project.
Each .fsproj file in the solution contains the line:

```
<Import Project="..\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets" />
```

But [docker's build context is limited by the project's folder](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2745)
and I'd rather not deal with that problem.

Can use Paket without the need for referring to parent folders?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert, but I guess you have two options here:

1. You can keep `Paket.Restore.targets` file in each project, which is not so bad IMHO.
2. In my project I decided to build docker image from parent folder, but yes you can do this by setting build context. If you decide here is a command I use:

   docker build -t "$IMAGE:$TAG_NAME" -f "$DOCKERFILE_PATH" .

I run it from parent level, and by `-f` you can specify Dockerfile and `.` at the end sets the context for build.

Comment: Setting the parent folder as build context causes the while directory (including my test scripts) to be sent to the Docker daemon.

Comment: So what are the steps to move the `Paket.Restore.targets` to my project folder without damaging the working project?

Comment: [This](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-folder.html) link says you should place the `.paket` directory at the root of you project.

Comment: @Mohsen you can use `.dockerignore` to exclude unwanted files/folders