# .Net Core Code Coverage for Linux in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, code-coverage

I have build and generated code coverage for a .Net Core Application using MiniCover and using TFS as a CI tool.

["https://github.com/lucaslorentz/minicover"](http://github.com/lucaslorentz/minicover)

Report has been generated in .xml, .html , .json and .txt format. Since I am using Linux Agent I am not able to publish my code coverage in TFS.

Could you please guys help on this

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use the build-in [Publish Code Coverage Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=vsts) task. Take a look at this topic-- [Publish Code Coverage Results not working on Linux with latest VSTS Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=vsts)

It's also able to publish code coverage result in Linux Agent. More details about step by step tutorial, please refer this blog: [Using VSTS to Test Python Code (with Code Coverage)](https://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/using-vsts-to-test-python-code-with-code-coverage)

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I want to build and test inside docker container. Is there any best approach to generate code coverage report and publish in TFS

Comment: @satheesh It's able to use publish test result task to publish test results in docker container. Take a look at  this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261711/how-to-configure-ci-for-dockerized-f-expecto-tests-on-tfs  which should be helpful to you. Not sure if it's also work with publish code coverage results.  VSTS only support to show the code coverage result published by "Publish Code Coverage Results" with "JaCoCo" or "Cobertura" format for now. If the coverage is in other format, the coverage result file will be published but the report won't show.